# google-cloud client library key file as json

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use the @google-cloud client library to authenticate using a service account. Is there a way to pass in the keyfile content as a JSON object rather than a file path? I don't want to store the key file on the server, rather use a secrets manager service, load the key file in memory and use it as needed.
The library seems to only take key file path:

```
const storage = new Storage({projectId:projectId, keyFilename: keyPath});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `credentials` parameter in the constructor: [storageOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#StorageOptions)

```
var sa_data = fs.readFileSync(keyPath);
var sa_json = JSON.parse(sa_data)

const storage = new Storage({
  credentials: sa_json
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.